# How to type cast a list of uint to a list of vr_ahb_data in Specman?

Tags: casting, specman, e

I have `A` which is a `list of uint(bits:20)` and `B` which is a `list of vr_ahb_data`. I also have a method that takes in 2 lists of `vr_ahb_data` and compares each item between the two lists.

```
type vr_ahb_data : uint(bits: VR_AHB_DATA_WIDTH); // defined in vr_ahb_types.e

// below are in my test bench environment
A : list of uint(bits:20);
B : list of vr_ahb_data;

data_check(act: list of vr_ahb_data, exp: list of vr_ahb_data) is {
    // compare each item in both lists
};
```

How do I type cast `A` to make it acceptable to the `data_check()` method ? I cannot change the method since it is a common utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that vr_ahb_data is some kind of an int, that is - defined something like this -

```
type vr_ahb_data : uint(bits : VR_AHB_DATA_WIDTH);
```

you can do the casting in the call

```
        data_check(A.as_a(list of vr_ahb_data), B);
```

Comment: But be careful in case that VR_AHB_DATA_WIDTH is smaller than 20: in this case, casting will also cut the values of more than VR_AHB_DATA_WIDTH bits, and you might get incorrect results.